# Un elemento Datalist de html5 conectado un servicio rest no se despliega al primer click, requiere de un segundo click

Tags: css, html5

Tengo un datalist que obtiene las opciones de un servicio rest. Al principio el datalist no tiene las opciones, esta vació. Cuando se hace click sobre el elemento (1er click - focus) obtiene los valores para las opciones pero no se despliega el datalist, es necesario hacer otro click (2do click) para abrir el datalist. Una vez que ya cargo las opciones, funciona normalmente.

¿Existe alguna forma de desplegar (*abrir*) un datalist por código, luego de cargar las opciones recibidas en el rest.?

**UPDATE**

Agrego la porción relevante del código.

Los datos se cargan correctamente en "`uas`" (muestra el spiner, etc) pero no despliega el datalist. Es necesario hacer un 2do click para desplegarlo.

```
<div class="threecol">
    <label for="ua">Seleccione</label> <input
        type="text" class="form-control" id="ua" name="ua"
        [(ngModel)]="model.ua" #ua="ngModel"
        (focus)="recuperarDatos()"/>  //trae las opciones
    <datalist id="uasId">
        <option *ngFor="let ua of uas" [ngValue]="ua.id">{{ua.id}}
            {{ua.descripcion}}</option>
    </datalist>
</div>

.ts 

    class example {
    ..
    ..
    recuperarDatos(){
        ...
        this.uas = obtenerDatosByRest();  //opciones

        //aca obtener el datalist y desplegarlo
    }
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido, te recomiendo leer este [link](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para mejorar tu pregunta

Comment: Inspecciona el datalist con clic derecho "inspeccionar elemento" y revisa tu codigo HTML para descubrir si tienes algun error, si todo se ve aparentemente bien, edita tu pregunta y pon el codigo HTML para ver si nosotros vemos algo que se te pudo pasar

Comment: @JoséAlexisCruzSolar gracias, ya edite la pregunta.

Comment: Recuperar datos es una llamada asincrona?, si es asi, pues puede estar pasando que demore mucho en cargar los datos del data list, y al segundo focus recien los está mostrando.

Comment: si entendí bien, la lista del `datalist` se comienza a cargar una vez haces un clic en ella(clic en input)?

Comment: @LPZadkiel El datalist obtiene las opciones de un servicio web cuando se le hace click en el input, si es correcto, pero no se despliega. Luego que recibió las opciones (muestra el clásico triangulo, con el hover del mouse) y al hacer el 2do click en el input despliega la lista. La que quiero saber es, si existe alguna forma de desplegarlo por código, para evitar el 2do click sobre el input.

Comment: @GabrielJeremyRodriguezRiver Si puede ser que este demorando mucho en cargar el datalist, por eso requiere de un 2do focus para desplegarlo, porque ya esta cargado. Existe alguna forma de desplegarlo, para evitar el 2do click?